# Google-cloud-run will not run Paketo Buildpacks built Springboot web image

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, paketo

I cannot run a spring-boot web image built with Paketo Buildpacks by spring-maven-plugin. Error says:

```
Deploying container to Cloud Run service [bff] in project [merchantloans] region [us-central1]
X  Deploying...                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  -  Creating Revision...                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  .  Routing traffic...
Deployment failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Revision 'bff-00002-wtm' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

Any ideas? Even if I try to set PORT=8080 environment variable in local docker it doesn't expose port 8080. Only if I use the docker -p argument does that work, but that doesn't seem to be available in google-cloud-run

```
[INFO] Building image 'docker.io/library/bff:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
[INFO]
[INFO]  > Pulling builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled builder image 'paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base@sha256:94593b2ad54362e1256da43631661d3dad936a177609a3d297fc638e87c6ee91'
[INFO]  > Pulling run image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/run-jammy-base:latest' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled run image 'paketobuildpacks/run-jammy-base@sha256:c2bc9ac828642aee2376a649ef5affd6912507c739247a40086bcae6d62a8b41'
[INFO]  > Executing lifecycle version v0.18.5
[INFO]  > Using build cache volume 'pack-cache-65773be3b4d2.build'
[INFO]
[INFO]  > Running creator
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> ANALYZING
[INFO]     [creator]     Restoring data for SBOM from previous image
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> DETECTING
[INFO]     [creator]     6 of 26 buildpacks participating
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates   3.6.7
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica 10.5.2
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/syft              1.44.0
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar    6.8.3
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/dist-zip          5.6.8
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot       5.27.8
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> RESTORING
[INFO]     [creator]     Restoring metadata for "paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates:helper" from app image
[INFO]     [creator]     Restoring metadata for "paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:helper" from app image
[INFO]     [creator]     Restoring metadata for "paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:java-security-properties" from app image
[INFO]     [creator]     Restoring metadata for "paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:jre" from app image
[INFO]     [creator]     Restoring metadata for "paketo-buildpacks/syft:syft" from cache
[INFO]     [creator]     Restoring metadata for "paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot:helper" from app image
[INFO]     [creator]     Restoring metadata for "paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot:spring-cloud-bindings" from app image
[INFO]     [creator]     Restoring metadata for "paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot:web-application-type" from app image
[INFO]     [creator]     Restoring data for "paketo-buildpacks/syft:syft" from cache
[INFO]     [creator]     Restoring data for SBOM from cache
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> BUILDING
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for CA Certificates 3.6.7
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Helper: Reusing cached layer
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for BellSoft Liberica 10.5.2
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica
[INFO]     [creator]       Build Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_JLINK_ARGS           --no-man-pages --no-header-files --strip-debug --compress=1  configure custom link arguments (--output must be omitted)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_JLINK_ENABLED        false                                                        enables running jlink tool to generate custom JRE
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_TYPE                 JRE                                                          the JVM type - JDK or JRE
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_VERSION              17                                                           the Java version
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_ENABLED           false                                                        enables Java remote debugging support
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_PORT              8000                                                         configure the remote debugging port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_SUSPEND           false                                                        configure whether to suspend execution until a debugger has attached
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_HEAP_DUMP_PATH                                                                       write heap dumps on error to this path
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_ENABLED        true                                                         enables Java Native Memory Tracking (NMT)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_LEVEL          summary                                                      configure level of NMT, summary or detail
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ARGS                                                                             configure custom Java Flight Recording (JFR) arguments
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ENABLED             false                                                        enables Java Flight Recording (JFR)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_ENABLED             false                                                        enables Java Management Extensions (JMX)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_PORT                5000                                                         configure the JMX port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_HEAD_ROOM           0                                                            the headroom in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_LOADED_CLASS_COUNT  35% of classes                                               the number of loaded classes in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT        250                                                          the number of threads in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS                                                                        the JVM launch flags
[INFO]     [creator]         Using Java version 17 extracted from MANIFEST.MF
[INFO]     [creator]       BellSoft Liberica JRE 17.0.10: Reusing cached layer
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Helper: Reusing cached layer
[INFO]     [creator]       Java Security Properties: Reusing cached layer
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for Syft 1.44.0
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/syft
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from https://github.com/anchore/syft/releases/download/v0.104.0/syft_0.104.0_linux_amd64.tar.gz
[INFO]     [creator]         Verifying checksum
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/SYFT_CHECK_FOR_APP_UPDATE.default
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for Executable JAR 6.8.3
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar
[INFO]     [creator]       Command "packages" is deprecated, use `syft scan` instead
[INFO]     [creator]       Class Path: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env/CLASSPATH.delim
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env/CLASSPATH.prepend
[INFO]     [creator]       Process types:
[INFO]     [creator]         executable-jar: java org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher (direct)
[INFO]     [creator]         task:           java org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher (direct)
[INFO]     [creator]         web:            java org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher (direct)
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for Spring Boot 5.27.8
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot
[INFO]     [creator]       Build Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_DISABLED   false  whether to contribute Spring Boot cloud bindings support
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_VERSION    1      default version of Spring Cloud Bindings library to contribute
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_DISABLED  false  whether to auto-configure Spring Boot environment properties from bindings
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_ENABLED   true   Deprecated - whether to auto-configure Spring Boot environment properties from bindings
[INFO]     [creator]       Creating slices from layers index
[INFO]     [creator]         dependencies (22.5 MB)
[INFO]     [creator]         spring-boot-loader (446.0 KB)
[INFO]     [creator]         snapshot-dependencies (0.0 B)
[INFO]     [creator]         application (117.4 KB)
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Helper: Reusing cached layer
[INFO]     [creator]       Spring Cloud Bindings 2.0.2: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bindings/2.0.2/spring-cloud-bindings-2.0.2.jar
[INFO]     [creator]         Verifying checksum
[INFO]     [creator]         Copying to /layers/paketo-buildpacks_spring-boot/spring-cloud-bindings
[INFO]     [creator]       Web Application Type: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Servlet web application detected
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.launch/BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT.default
[INFO]     [creator]       4 application slices
[INFO]     [creator]       Image labels:
[INFO]     [creator]         org.opencontainers.image.title
[INFO]     [creator]         org.opencontainers.image.version
[INFO]     [creator]         org.springframework.boot.version
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> EXPORTING
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates:helper'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:helper'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:java-security-properties'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:jre'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar:classpath'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot:helper'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot:spring-cloud-bindings'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot:web-application-type'
[INFO]     [creator]     Adding layer 'buildpacksio/lifecycle:launch.sbom'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing 3/5 app layer(s)
[INFO]     [creator]     Adding 2/5 app layer(s)
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'buildpacksio/lifecycle:launcher'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'buildpacksio/lifecycle:config'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'buildpacksio/lifecycle:process-types'
[INFO]     [creator]     Adding label 'io.buildpacks.lifecycle.metadata'
[INFO]     [creator]     Adding label 'io.buildpacks.build.metadata'
[INFO]     [creator]     Adding label 'io.buildpacks.project.metadata'
[INFO]     [creator]     Adding label 'org.opencontainers.image.title'
[INFO]     [creator]     Adding label 'org.opencontainers.image.version'
[INFO]     [creator]     Adding label 'org.springframework.boot.version'
[INFO]     [creator]     Setting default process type 'web'
[INFO]     [creator]     Saving docker.io/library/bff:1.0-SNAPSHOT...
[INFO]     [creator]     *** Images (506f57c215a7):
[INFO]     [creator]           docker.io/library/bff:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing cache layer 'paketo-buildpacks/syft:syft'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing cache layer 'buildpacksio/lifecycle:cache.sbom'
[INFO] 
[INFO] Successfully built image 'docker.io/library/bff:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11.917 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-03-01T13:32:15-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: A Spring Boot app built with Paketo buildpacks will listen on port 8080 by default, because that's the port on which Spring Boot will listen by default. There's nothing else you need to do. The fact that docker requires `docker run -p` to expose a port is just a factor of how Docker works. It doesn't expose anything unless you tell it to. I don't know how Google Cloud Run works, if there is configuration you need to set. I can say that your app, if it starts correctly, is definitely listening on port 8080 unless you've changed the port on which it will listen in your Spring app configuration.

Comment: Do you have application logs? You should see your container starting and your Spring Boot app starting. It will also show you the port on which it is listening.

Comment: Well, Google Cloud Run doesn't allow one to specificy docker parameters. I can make an image that works on GCR by putting 'EXPOSE 8080' in the dockerfile. I can run a Paketo built image manually by specifying `docker run -p` as you mentioned, but unless the image is built and something in the metadata says port 8080 is exposed then it doesn't work for GCR. There are no application logs because the application doesn't start.

Comment: What tool are you using to run the build? Spring Boot Build tools?

Comment: Yes, I am using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` with the `build-image` goal and no additional configurations.

Comment: OK, I just double-checked and Buildpacks don't have a facility to expose a port like `EXPOSE` in a Dockerfile. That said, I know Google Cloud Run works with buildpacks because they have their own set of buildpacks. It may be that they are doing something unique in their buildpacks or possibly have different tooling surrounding the buildpacks to adjust the metadata and expose that port. I'm guessing cause I'm not familiar with Google Cloud Run. You might try their buildpack/tooling and see if that works.

Comment: Cloud Run looks at port 8080 by default as a part of the container contract https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#port

I wonder if the default configuration of the buildpack you're using isn't serving on 8080? You can change the default port using https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/services/containers#command-line

Comment: From what I can see the best way to get this working is to use the `pack` cli and set the port argument during the build. See [Set environment variables to configure builds](https://cloud.google.com/docs/buildpacks/set-environment-variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track! Using the pack CLI and setting the port argument during the build is a good approach to ensure your Spring Boot web image listens on the correct port for Google Cloud Run.

Steps:

1. Build with `pack` CLI:

```
pack build my-spring-boot-app:latest --env PORT=8080
```

- Replace `my-spring-boot-app:latest` with your application name and tag.
- This sets the `PORT` environment variable to 8080 within the container image.

2. Push and Deploy:

- Push the built image to your container registry.
- Deploy the image to Cloud Run using `gcloud run deploy`:

```
gcloud run deploy SERVICE_NAME --image REGISTRY_URL/my-spring-boot-app:latest
```

- Replace placeholders with your actual values.

This approach ensures your application listens on the expected port (8080) for Cloud Run.

**Documentation Reference:**

- [pack CLI - Setting Environment Variables](https://github.com/buildpacks/github-actions)
- [Google Cloud Run - Deploying Container Images](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying)
- [Set environment variables to configure builds](https://cloud.google.com/docs/buildpacks/set-environment-variables)

Comment: Ok, I was able to do this with the google build packs and it was running fine. The google build packs do add an `EXPOSE 8080` in a layer. The above command worked fine and also I was able to do a [Remote Build](https://cloud.google.com/docs/buildpacks/build-application#remote_builds) except for Windows I had to issue the command from WSL so that `gradlew` was marked a runnable by linux. Do you think that is a bug?

Comment: As a follow up, if I delete `gradlew` or `mvnw` from the project then `google-cloud-build` will use a built in mvn or gradle that is not subject to unix permission issues.